# Using Apache POI with RegEx to extract Uppercase Words

Tags: java, regex

So I am working on a Project to extract Uppercase words out of a .doc file in Java.  I am using regex, but the regex below was used by someonelse in a old .vba script.  I need to find All Uppercase Words that are surrounded by Parenthesis.  For Example (WORD).  I know the regex below will give me a dangling meta character error so what would the regex be for this.

```
private static final String REGEX = "(*[A-Z]*[A-Z]*)";
private void parseWordText(File file) throws IOException { 
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file); 
    HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs); 
    WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc); 
    if (we.getParagraphText() != null) { 
        String[] dataArray = we.getParagraphText(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) { 
            String data = dataArray[i].toString(); 
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX); 
            Matcher m = p.matcher(data); 
            List<String> sequences = new Vector<String>(); 
            while (m.find()) { 
                sequences.add(data.substring(m.start(), m.end())); 
                System.out.println(data.substring(m.start(), m.end())); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

With the code above and the regex I am getting two upper case letters, not just the all upper case words with the parens.

Comment: That Regex doesn't do what you're saying it does - it matches an arbitrary number of Upper Case letters(including none) after an arbitrary number of left parens (including none), followed by one right paren.  `)`, `()`, and `(((((((((AA)` all match this regex.  Is that what you want?  Or are you solely looking for `(AA)`?  What about `(  A )`, or `( A A )`?

Comment: Sorry didn't explain well.  Any amount of Upper case letters that are after a left parens and before a right parens.  But when I use regex in java it is giving me a dangling meta character error.

Comment: Should it be more than one Upper case letter (should `()` match)?  Also, what package are you using to compile this regular expression?  Could you give us the actual code?

Comment: Its the java regex package... see edited code above.

Comment: But to answer your question about More than one upper case letter yes it should. It could be any number of letters as long as they are all uppercase and enclosed in parens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses are reserved character in regular expressions, so your first `*` is not modifying anything.  At the very least, you need to escape them:

```
\(*[A-Z]*[A-Z]*\)
```

However, don't stop reading yet!  It should be noted that the regex above is identical to:

```
\(*[A-Z]*\)
```

But most importantly, I don't think that is the regular expression you want.  I think you're trying to capture a non-zero number of sequential capital letters surrounded by parentheses, or:

```
\([A-Z]+\)
```

The '+' is a one or more match, and you'll noticed I've stopped repeating the left paren.  For bonus points, you may want to handle whitespace at the beginning or end of the parenthetical:

```
\(\s*[A-A]+\s*\)
```

But be aware that that will match across new lines.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Sweet man, thanks Frankie...I appreciate the quick response on that.  I am very strong on Java but I have never really used regex's that much.

Comment: Now one more question what if I was trying to capture Uppercase letters more than two like [A-Z][A-Z]+ but just looking for any digits anywhere in there.

Comment: So, starting with an uppercase character, then followed by at least one uppercase character or digit?  `[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+`  By the way, arbitrary repetition can be done in regex with `A{min,max}`, so if it's just two or more Capitals: `[A-Z]{2,}`, and exact repetition simply eschews the comma.

Comment: Yes starts with an uppercase letter but could contain a number and the rest of the letters are uppercase.

Comment: Now if it started with a number then ended with uppercase letters is that the point where I would need a lookback?

Comment: Not that I can think of.   `[0-9][A-Z]+`  <-- is that what you meant?  Let's chat this, as we're veering off the original topic of the question.

Comment: Ok I am new here where do I go to chat this

Comment: @MarkBasler I don't know.  Usually it asks you after a few back and forths if you want to move to a private chat.  Maybe the annotations will help?

Comment: It appears that you don't have enough reputation to chat yet.  Oh, well.  Did all that Answer your questions?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response too.